# svndumpfilter fails with "Invalid copy source path..." error

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svndumpfilter

I want to move part of my SVN repo offsite, onto an AWS instance & am following this page ([Repository Maintenance](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s03.html))

I have taken a `dump` of the whole repo (Windows commands):

- `svnadmin dump c:\repo > all_repo`

Next is to filter it, to include only the project I am interested in (which is called "M1").

- `type all_repo | svndumpfilter include M1 --drop-empty-revs > m1`

I know this is correct, as I have done it on some of the other projects already.

---

On this project, it breaks with the error indicated in the title of this post. The exact wording is:

> svndumpfilter: Invalid copy source path '/Personal/Richard/M1_Config'
>
> The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.

The folder that the error refers to is a configuration utility that I wrote and submitted under my personal folder, and it is not under the root/m1... folder at all. I do not want to include it in the filtered file, but do not know how to indicate this to the svn commands.

1. How can I correctly filter for the whole M1 folder and its children, while excluding the Personal/Richard/M1_Config folder entirely?
2. How can I be sure whether the exported file contains the correct information to correctly recreate the M1 folder on the remote SVN?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

At some point `/Personal/Richard/M1_Config` has been copied to the `M1` path. The error message is say that it can't perform the copy since the source has been filtered out. Check the revision that svndumpfilter complained about.

You must include the `/Personal/Richard/M1_Config` path even if you don't want it in the final import. You also need to include the `/Personal/Richard` and `/Personal` paths since each resides in it's parent. Your command needs to be:

```
type all_repo | svndumpfilter include M1 "/Personal" --drop-empty-revs > m1
```

If you have other paths, say `/Personal/James` that aren't needed and you wish to exclude them then you can run a second svndumpfilter to strip them:

```
type m1 | svndumpfilter exclude "/Personal/James" --drop-empty-revs > m1_2
```

Comment: Is there a sinple way to figure out witch parts have to be includet. I am working with try and error at the moment.

Comment: You could search through the changesets and look for 'copy-from-path' that affect the path of interest. You could do this by a text search through a dump file, or perhaps with svnlook.

Answer (score 19):

I've tried at least 4 different applications to do that, the only that **really worked was using  [svndumpfilterIN](https://github.com/jasperlee108/svndumpfilterIN)** :

```
svnadmin dump c:\repo > all_repo
svndumpfilter.py all_repo --repo=c:\repo --output-dump=m1 include M1
```

Here is my [full answer on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22194572/535203).

Here is what I tried and **didn't worked** :

- http://furius.ca/pubcode/pub/conf/bin/svndumpfilter3.html ([from previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1170429/535203))
- Including the problematic path as said in [another previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/896076/535203) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13513372/535203). Problem : I still have paths I do not want in the target dump
- [svndumpsanitizer](https://github.com/dsuni/svndumpsanitizer) (I still have paths I do not want in the target dump also)

Comment: Seriously, thanks for the post. After spending a lot of time, this was the only thing that worked flawlessly.

Comment: Worked well for me too.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting the "Invalid copy source..." error when specifying a pattern - in our case it's --pattern "*.config". However svndumpfilterIN doesn't support --pattern. If anyone can suggest a fruitful approach, I'd be most appreciative.

Comment: Thanks so much for that: it works perfectly and doesn't have the flaws of svndumpfilter. The dump is really lighter since the unnecessary paths are really ignored.

Answer (score 5):

I run into the same problem. We have many remotely moved and copied paths in the repository and the only tool that really helped was [svndumpsanitizer](https://github.com/dsuni/svndumpsanitizer) A single file C program that easily can be compiled on cygwin or Linux and it worked like a charm on a 170 GB incremental dump file with ~160,000 commits.

Comment: Worked for me !

Comment: This is really the best solution.  svndumpsanitizer is what svndumpfitler should have been.

Comment: svndumpsanitizer worked from the first try! If anyone lacks gcc and considers a quick compile in a C++ console app in Visual Studio, svndumpsanitizer.c is easily adaptable.