# Syncing SVN projects with TRAC

Tags: svn, repository, trac

I have a TRAC (version 1.0) and SVN server (version 1.7.8) installed on my system (Ubuntu 12.04). There are many **svn projects** in repository (/var/lib/svn) and correspondingly many **trac projects** in trac environment (/var/lib/trac).

Now I would like to *sync between each project of SVN with it's corresponding project in TRAC. I know there are traditional ways to sync a TRAC project with ***complete*** svn repository. But how to achieve the same among projects ?

Thanks in advance.

*sync - make source browsable from trac page and also view commit changes, revision numbers etc.

Comment: It's unclear what you really want to do. Version numbers (revision numbers) are unique in a repository. If you have many projects in one repository, they will always share the HEAD revision number, even if the changes to them were made in older revision. Please also note that commit hooks are executed per-repo, not per-project, making it *very* hard (if not quite impossible) to make trac differentiate between changes to individual projects.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, the goal is to provide sourcecode of each svn project made available to _it's corresposing_ trac project. In the current scenario, when I sync svn repos with trac - source code of every project is seen ! Is the objective clear now ?

Comment: Well, the objective is clear, but why don't you just have one repo per project? That would make a lot more sense.

Comment: But _these svn projects_ have been part of repos since quite some time and our team can't afford to lose all the revisions. Is there any way to do it among projects ?

Comment: For new projects, that would be a better solution, but what about existing ones ?

Comment: I'd say the more you stay with the current setup, the worse things will get. I'm sure, however, that it's possible to split these repos while still keeping the revisions.

Comment: You can [split](http://stackoverflow.com/q/433276/33499) the svn repository into different projects, one repository for each project.

Comment: Thanks for the insights .. will do the needful.